# Indicadores, talib, como usarlo con la api de binance?

Tags: python

```
def funciones(var, var1):
#resta volumen nuevo menos volumen viejo
volumen = float(var1[1]) - float(var[2])
#saca porcentaje del precio desde ke se lanzo el script
preciopor = ((float(var1[0])/float(var[1]))*100)-100
#pasa porcentaje a 3 digitos
porcentaje = format(preciopor, '.2f')
#extrae los precios historicos en velas de 1 hora desde hace 60 dias
klines = client.get_historical_klines(var[0], Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR, "10 day ago UTC")
lista = []
lista1 = []
lista2 = []
suma = 0
#agrega los precios de cierre a una lista para extraer las resistencias
for x in klines:
    lista.append(x[4])`
```

con este codigo consigo los precios de una moneda específica, de 10 dias`atras, ahora lo que me interesa es meterlo en un numy.array para poder usarlo con la libreria de TA-lib, pero no me lo toma, lo estoy haciendo asi

```
listas = np.array([lista])
```

y cuando quiero usar TA-lib buscando una Media movil con

```
output = SMA(lista1, timeperiod=25)
```

me tira este error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "talib/_abstract.pxi", line 352, in talib._ta_lib.Function.__call__
  File "talib/_abstract.pxi", line 383, in talib._ta_lib.Function.__call_function
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/talib/__init__.py", line 24, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "talib/_func.pxi", line 9908, in talib._ta_lib.SMA
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Personalmente no conozco TA-Lib ni su wrapper por lo que esto es solo una suposición, buscando en el sitio en inglés he encontrado esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777651/ta-lib-python-wrapper-only-length-1-arrays-error. Pudiera ser un solapamiento de namespaces. Prueba a importar con `import talib` y llama a la función con `output = talib.SMA(lista1, timeperiod=25)`

Comment: recien me di cuenta que escribiste, jaja perdon y muchas gracias